# Any info on why clearRect is causing page wide faults when referenced in code path? codepen for reference

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, codepen

I am trying to create a 'hangman' display for my hangman game with the HTML canvas element. I got the hangman to display one step at a time but I can't seem to clear the canvas (was expecting it to be the easier step...). When I add the clearRect call it causes my whole page to fault out. Can't start the game etc - even when I call it only at the end of a game...

Any advice would be appreciated - new to the web world so assuming I'm doing something silly :)

See the following code pen for the source files and a display of the issue: 
https://codepen.io/enewmanMN/pen/LYPWpQq

Tried moving the clearRect call around to avoid calling it right away to see if I could even get the game started with it in the code path but not having any luck.

https://codepen.io/enewmanMN/pen/LYPWpQq

```
function clearCanvas () {
    myStickman = document.getElementById("stickman");
    context = myStickman.getContext('2d');
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //CAUSING FAULTS
    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = "#fff";
    context.lineWidth = 2;
}
```

Was expecting it to clear the canvas element 'stickman' but instead loose functionality to the page.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code with the clearRect uncommented, I got an error saying canvas is not defined. You gave the canvas the name `myStickman`. This fixed it

```
context.clearRect(0, 0, myStickman.width, myStickman.height);
```